# Dart/Flutter - How to delete key-value-pairs of element of Map inside a List?

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

How can I can delete a specific key-value-pair in that type of List<Map<String, dynamic>> for each map.

**For example:**

List<Map<String, dynamic>> **before** the operation:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> currencies = [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'coin',
      'desc': 'This is just a blindtext.',
      'order': 101,
      'icon': 'https://icon1.jpg'
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'karma',
      'desc': 'This is just a blindtext.',
      'order': 102,
      'icon': 'https://icon2.jpg'
    },
    {
      'id': 3,
      'name': 'laurel',
      'desc': 'This is just a blindtext.',
      'order': 104,
      'icon': 'https://icon3.jpg'
    },
  ];
```

List<Map<String, dynamic>> **after** the operation I am searching for:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> currencies = [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'coin',
      'icon': 'https://icon1.jpg'
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'karma',
      'icon': 'https://icon2.jpg'
    },
    {
      'id': 3,
      'name': 'laurel',
      'icon': 'https://icon3.jpg'
    },
  ];
```

So basically, I deleted "unwanted" key-value-pairs.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
currencies.forEach((item) => item..remove("order")..remove("desc"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried something similar but it didn't work out as I wanted!!